# Can chrome's API be used to switch between multiple chrome devtools?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I am developing a chrome devtool of my own. I need to click a button from my devtool to jump to chrome's network panel. Is this possible? , I looked for a lot of documents, and I didn’t see any relevant implementation.

for example:

```
chrome.devtools.open('network',function callback(){})
```

then the network panel will show

thank you.

Comment: There's no such API.

Comment: @wOxxOm 
So this idea cannot be realized?